# Cannot delete histograms from skimr output

Tags: r, skimr

By my reading of the R package [skimr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/skimr/vignettes/skimr.html), this should produce output without inline histograms. What am I doing wrong? Error message is attached.

```
my_skim <- skim_with(numeric = sfl(hist=NULL))
my_skim(faithful)

Error in `dplyr::summarize()`:
ℹ In argument: `skimmed = purrr::map2(...)`.
Caused by error in `purrr::map2()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: numeric.
Caused by error in `dplyr::summarize()`:
ℹ In argument: `dplyr::across(variable_names, mangled_skimmers$funs)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! `.fns` must be a function, a formula, or a list of functions/formulas.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
>
```

Comment: Which package version do you have? Your code works on my machine: packageVersion("skimr")
[1] ‘2.1.5’

Comment: 2.1.3 I'll try to update.